# Scand realm browser android studio ERROR

Tags: java, android, realm

So I have this error when trying to view the Realm browser that Scand provides.
http://scand.com/products/realmbrowser/index.html
I see the realm browser too which opens, and it says there's 123kb of data but there is nothing there. I need someone to explain how to remove this error and also to see the data using this browser. Thanks

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method allObjects(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lio/realm/RealmResults; in class Lio/realm/Realm; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.realm.Realm' appears    in /data/data/com.example.android.chargerpoints/files/instant-run/dex/slice-io.realm-realm-android-library-2.3.0_b9f663d7b6a9da482eea50e15de849b801c361b6-classes.dex)
 at com.scand.realmbrowser.ClassListAdapter.updateData(ClassListAdapter.java:73)
                  at com.scand.realmbrowser.ClassListAdapter.<init>(ClassListAdapter.java:65)
                  at com.scand.realmbrowser.DbConfigBrowserFragment.updateUIData(DbConfigBrowserFragment.java:175)
                  at com.scand.realmbrowser.DbConfigBrowserFragment.initUI(DbConfigBrowserFragment.java:159)
                  at com.scand.realmbrowser.DbConfigBrowserFragment.onActivityCreated(DbConfigBrowserFragment.java:89)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2193)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1323)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2832)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

*Update

Build Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
            maven {
                url 's3://assets.scand.com/maven/repository/RealmBrowser'
                credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                    accessKey "XXXXX"
                    secretKey "XXXXX"
                }
            }
            jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And I also have this in the app's build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.scand:realm-browser:0.1.13'
```

Comment: can you post your `build.gradle`? also can you disable instant run & see if it works

Comment: I added the build.gradle above

Comment: Clearly the problem is that scand's Realm Browser is **so old** that it doesn't support Realm above version 0.91.0.